Path integral at large time
From the path integral of a QFT:
$$Z=\int D\phi e^{-S[\phi]}$$
What is a nice argument to say that when we study the theory at large time $T$, this behaves as:
$$ Z \to e^{-TE_0} $$
where $E_0$ is the minimum energy of the system.

Briefly speaking, the standard argument is

A correspondence between the path integral formalism and the operator formalism in Minkowskian signature with unitary time evolution;

Wick rotate both sides of the correspondence to Euclidean signature;

(Optional.) Identify with the partition function in statistical mechanics, where the Euclidean time becomes the inverse temperature $\beta$;

Take the limit
$$ Z~=~{\rm Tr}_{\cal H}e^{-\beta \hat{H}}\quad\sim\quad e^{-\beta E_0}\quad\text{for}\quad\beta\to\infty,$$
where $E_0$ is the ground state.



Path integral and operator formalism correspondence states that for Euclidean time $t$, $$Z=\int D\phi e^{-S[\phi]}\leftrightarrow Z~=~{\rm Tr}_{\cal H}(e^{-t\hat{H}})$$
Fix an orthonormal basis $\{|n\rangle\}_{n}\in \mathcal{H}$ for the Hilbert space of the theory. Then by using the following identities
$$\langle m|n\rangle = \delta_{mn}\quad\space \sum_{n}|n\rangle\langle n| = \hat{\text{I}}$$
We can obtain the spectral decomposition for eigenstates $H|n\rangle = E_n|n\rangle$
$$e^{-tH} = e^{-tH}\biggr(\sum_{n}|n\rangle\langle n|\biggr) = \sum_{n}e^{-tH}|n\rangle\langle n| = \sum_{n}e^{-tE_n}|n\rangle\langle n|$$
Which leads us to
$${\rm Tr}_{\cal H}(e^{-t\hat{H}}) = \sum_{n}e^{-tE_n} = e^{-tE_0}\biggr(1+\sum_{n}e^{-t(E_n-E_0)}\biggr)\sim e^{-tE_0}\quad(t\rightarrow\infty)$$

I'm assuming you mean immaginary time $T$. In this case the path integral is equal to the partition function (with $T=\beta$), as others have noted.  Then, let the spectral decomposition of $H$ be
$$
H=\sum_n E_n \Pi_n,
$$
where $\Pi_n$ are (not necessarily one-dimensional) eigenprojectors. Then, ordering the eigenvalues of $H$, $\{E_n\}$, in increasing order: $E_0 < E_1 < E_2<\ldots$, and with degeneracies given by $g_n=\mathrm{Tr} \Pi_n$, we have
\begin{align}
Z &= \mathrm{Tr} e^{-\beta H}\\
&= \sum_{n=0} g_n e^{-\beta E_n}\\
&= e^{-\beta E_0} g_0 \left (1+ \sum_{n=1} e^{-\beta \Delta_n} g_n/g_0 \right )\\
&= e^{-\beta E_0} g_0 \left (1+ e^{-\beta \Delta_1} g_1/g_0 + O(e^{-\beta \Delta_2}) \right ),
\end{align}
valid when $\beta\to \infty$ and having defined $\Delta_n := E_n-E_0>0$.
Usually the ground state is non-degenerate, i.e. $g_0=1$, which gives your equation ($\beta$ is the imaginary time).
